# Difficulties with RectangleF

Tags: c#, xna

I always get this error message? What is wrong? How can I use the type RectangleF?

The type or namespace name 'RectangleF' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have reference to System.Drawing and using statment to it?

Comment: When you get this error. Can you provide the code sniped ?

Comment: Have you added a `using` statement for `System.Drawing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `System.Drawing` reference to your project

- Right click "References"
- "Add Reference..."
- ".NET" tab
- select "System.Drawing"
- "OK".

Comment: Thanx. It worked, but now I get another error message in the following line: spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Vector2(200, 200), Color.White);   'Color' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color' and 'System.Drawing.Color'

Comment: You need to specify wich `Color` object you want to use. Either `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color` or `System.Drawing.Color`. If you are using an XNA method, you need to send a `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color`